# Child travelling with non-relative adult on Air Baltic

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, children, airbaltic

I will soon be flying with Air Baltic from London to Tbilisi, transferring in Riga. Along with my family, my friends' child will be travelling with us. The child is 11 years old and will be staying with our family for the duration of the trip.

What kind of letter or anything else do I need to get from this child's parents? I assume I'd need to present something to the airline staff in London, possibly in Riga, likely in Tbilisi passport control; and the same on the way back - to alleviate any concerns about potential child abduction or trafficking. Obviously, this child will be travelling voluntarily with their parent's permission.

Answer (score 3):

You must get the permission of everyone with parental responsibility for a child or from a court before taking the child abroad. Typically a letter from the person(s) with parental responsibility for the child will suffice and should include the other person’s contact details and details about the trip.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/permission-take-child-abroad

See also https://www.airbaltic.com/en/children-travelling-alone “children of UK citizens need parental permission to travel independently or accompanied by an authorized person”

Comment: Thanks. I can get a letter signed by both parents, providing contact details, etc. Moreover, one of the child's parents will be with us at the airport during the check in. BTW, does the letter need to be notarised?

Comment: @AleksG None of the links mention that notarising the letter is required, however if you’re worried there would be no harm in doing it